# How should I fix the error when running composer install

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I am trying to do my first Laravel project.

I just changed the port `80` to `3000` in my XAMPP and I had an error when running `first.test:3000/example` to access my `routes.php` file. So, I'm just going to run:

```
composer install
```

to fix the commands but I have the below shown error. My PHP version is `7` and my Laravel version is `5.2`:

> PHP Warning: 
>   require(C:\xampp\htdocs\first\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\first\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening
>   required'C:\xampp\htdocs\first\boot strap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\first\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event
>   returned with error code 255

Comment: Do you have a virtual host or you access the project folder directly?

Comment: Try composer update --no-scripts

Comment: @thefallen I have a vhost ofcourse I am just learning it

Comment: Remove `php artisan clear-compiled` from the pre-update-cmd in your composer.json, then run composer install again. You can add it back in afterwards.

Comment: Are you pointing the vhost to your public map?  `C:/xampp/htdocs/PROJECTNAME/public`

Comment: @Mike Yes ofcourse